# print gtsummary table with print() with wrong footnote format

Tags: r-markdown, gtsummary

In my Rmarkdown report, I have to put a gtsummary table under an if statement, which requires `print()` to explicitly print it. However, the printout does not have the right format for the footnote. What did I miss, and how do I fix this?
Code:

```
stats_summary_table <-
    dat_wide %>%
    tbl_summary(by = id, 
                missing = "no",
                digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(0, 0, 1, 1, 3)),
                type = list(all_numeric() ~ "continuous"),
                statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ 
                                   "{min} ~ {max} {mean} ± {sd} [{cv}]")) %>%
      modify_footnote(starts_with("stat_") ~ "Range and mean±SD [cv]")
  
  
  if (n_distinct(dat_wide$id) > 1) {
    stats_summary_table <- stats_summary_table %>%  
      add_stat(
        fns = everything() ~ cal_cv,  
        fmt_fun = NULL,
        header = "**%CV**",
        footnote = "Coefficient of variation") %>%
      add_p()
  }

  
  print(stats_summary_table)
```

implicit printout by `stats_summary_table`.
[image]

explicit printout by `print(stats_summary_table)`.
[image]

Comment: Hello @ju. This is a formatting issue I was not aware of that  also is present in the gt package. Here's an example https://rpubs.com/ddsjoberg/688904

Have you search the gt documentation/help for a solution?  I don't have time at the moment to search, but I'll try to take a look in the coming days.

Comment: Hey hey, this looks like a known issue in gt https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/614